# Unable to determine how to override java base class from scala

Tags: scala

Following is a method in a java base class

```
public interface BenchmarkDriver {
    public boolean test(Map<Object, Object> ctx) throws Exception;
```

Here is the Scala class:

```
class SparkSqlQueryBenchmark extends BenchmarkDriver
```

And my (incorrect) attempt to override the java interface method:

```
@throws(classOf[java.lang.Exception])
override def test(ctx: java.util.Map[java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object]) : java.lang.Boolean =  {
```

Here is the compiler error:

```
[ERROR]  SparkAbstractBenchmark.scala:24: error: class SparkAbstractBenchmark needs to be abstract, since method test in trait BenchmarkDriver 
of type (x$1: java.util.Map[Object,Object])Boolean is not defined
SparkSqlQueryBenchmark.scala:30: error: overriding method test in trait BenchmarkDriver
 of type (x$1: java.util.Map[Object,Object])Boolean;
    [ERROR]  method test has incompatible type
    [ERROR]    override def test(ctx: java.util.Map[java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object])
 : java.lang.Boolean =  {
    [ERROR]
```

So what needs to be fixed on the scala override side?

**Update** After Marth's suggestion to change to Boolean

```
@throws(classOf[java.lang.Exception])
override def test(ctx: java.util.Map[java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object]) : Boolean =  {
```

Error looks similar but in any case here it is

```
[ERROR]  SparkAbstractBenchmark.scala:24: error: class SparkAbstractBenchmark needs
 to be abstract, since method test in trait BenchmarkDriver of type (x$1: 
java.util.Map[Object,Object])Boolean is not defined
[ERROR] class SparkAbstractBenchmark(cacheName: String) extends BenchmarkDriverAdapter {
[ERROR]       ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Scala's `Boolean` is not equivalent to Java's `Boolean` but to `boolean`.

Either change the Scala method to return a `Boolean` (not a `java.lang.Boolean`), or change the Java interface to return a `Boolean`.

---

Basically :

```
  Java  |      Scala
----------------------------
Boolean | java.lang.Boolean
boolean | Boolean
```

Comment: thx Marth.  I made that change but get same error. Could be additional issue(s) here?  btw I updated the OP with this info.

Comment: @javadba are you sure it's the same error? at least it should show different return type for the `test` method.

Comment: That's strange, it works for me… (although I did have to change `extends BenchmarkDriverAdapter` to `extends BenchmarkDriver`). Could you show the code of `BenchmarkDriverAdapter` ?

Comment: Posted the error message - I did not see any difference but in any case it is there.

Comment: There is extraneous code in that interface. I will instead take it out and make a custom class - to replicate the way you did it yourself.

Comment: I found it compiled when changing from Map[java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object] to Map[AnyRef, AnyRef]. Any idea ?  btw I am upvoting your answer for being helpful.

Comment: @javadba : That's weird, both `java.lang.Object` and`AnyRef` work for me using Scala 2.11.6. What version of Scala are you using ?